# Could power cycling a modem 24 times a day for over 3 years (>30,000 times) cause the modem to lose its settings?

Tags: communication, reset, modem, router

Could power cycling a modem 24 times a day with it being on for 10mins at a time for over 3 years (>30,000 times) cause the modem to lose its setting and revert to factory?

[This modem.](https://www.3grouterstore.co.uk/3G/Proroute_H820_LTE_4G_Router.html)

Comment: Maybe. Do you have reason to believe that it would? There could be many other reasons the modem will not survive 30.000 power cycles as this could stress many components (notably power supplies).

Comment: If you have the need to reset that modem every hour then maybe you need a better modem and/or a better connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, depending on how the firmware was written it may have worn out the EEPROM (typically good for >100,000 writes). That's not normal operation and they may not have tested for it.

On the other hand, a cheaply designed reset circuit and memory protection could result in corruption and therefore revert to defaults from a single upset.

Comment: great thanks for the info ill look into EEPROM, there is quite a lot of them out for many years and only now some have begun to fail. and one lost their settings once they seem to be likely to do it again.

Comment: Yes, if there is no battery then EEPROM would be highly suspect. Replacing it (they're usually a small 8-pin package with a number such as XX24Cxx or XX25Cxx) can restore the product.

Comment: thanks for the advice. just a question on why. why does power cycling the modem causes you to write to the EEPROM and subsequently burn it out rather than just read saved settings from it? Thanks.

Comment: It depends on how the firmware is written. You can put a logic analyzer on the chip and see if writes are taking place on power cycling.